# Mod rewrite / remove slash behind .html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a mod rewrite 301 that remove a slash behind the .html from the url.

Example:

Good URL: http://www.example.org/some-stuff-t123.html
Bad URL: http://www.example.org/some-stuff-t123.html/abcdesftesttest

The Bad URL with a / after the html should rewrited (301) to the good URL.

I need a request URI that detect a /* after the html and if yes, rewrite it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\.html/ /$1.html
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/ /$1.html [L,R=301]
```

If you have other rewrite rules, make sure the one that redirects is before any rules you may already have.

Comment: thank you so much. Both suggestions works perfect. which one should I take? which one you prefer?

Comment: @user2057781 it doesn't matter, but if you have other rewrite rules, it may conflict with mod_alias' `RedirectMatch`. Otherwise, it doesn't matter.